# Perfino triggers and workdays

Tags: perfino

Is there a way to configure a threshold violation trigger so that it only fires Monday-Friday and doesn't fire on weekends? I don't see any option in the Thresholds or Triggers menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of perfino 4, such a feature is not available. I've added it to our issue tracker.